# do I need to fill all the IDT exception entries, before handling IRQs?

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, interrupt-handling, irq

I was trying to handle IRQs but it didn't work, do I need to fill all the exception entries before doing any IRQs and remapping the PIC.

can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: No, only the entries that can potentially actually fire.  (Both external interrupts and any exceptions your code might cause, like #DE divide exception.)  Run your freestanding code in a simulator like Bochs so you can see how the machine crashed, if / when that happens.